# Abaqus: parametric geometry/assembly in Inputfile or Python script?

Tags: python, abaqus

i want to do something as a parametric study in Abaqus, where the parameter i am changing is a part of the assembly/geometry. 
Imagine the following:

A cube is hanging on 8 ropes. Each two of the 8 ropes line up in one corner of a room. the other ends of the ropes merge with the room diagonal of the cube. It's something like a cable-driven parallel robot/rope robot.

Now, i want to calculate the forces in the ropes in different positions of the cube, while only 7 of the 8 ropes are actually used. That means i have 8 simulations for each position of my cube.

I wrote a matlab script to generate the nodes and wires of the cube in different positions and angle of rotations so i can copy them into an input file for Abaqus.

Since I'm new to Abaqus scripting etc, i wonder which is the best way to make this work.

would you guys generate 8 input files for one position of the cube and calculate 
them manually or is there a way to let abaqus somehow iterate different assemblys?

I guess i should wright a python script, but i don't know how to make the ropes the parameter that is changing.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks, Tobi

Comment: Maybe i generate a uniqe input file for each position and iterate the parameter in a python script where the parameter is the elementset containing the 7 ropes. I could define 8 element sets with different rope combination (each time 7 ropes) and iterate through these element sets?!

Comment: In my opinion, It's much easier to do it by creating unique input files for each location. Parametric studies are useful for studies with parameters being simple variables like dimensions (maybe different rope dia or material properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someon is interested, i was able to do it the following way:

I created a model in abaqus till the point, i could have started the job. Then i took the .jnl file (which is created automaticaly by abaqus) and saved it as a .py file. Then i modified this script by defining every single point as a variable and every wire for the parts as tuples, consisting out of the variables. Than i made for loops and for every 9 cases unique wire definitions, which i called during the loop. During the loop also the constraints were changed and the job were started. I also made a field output request for the endnodes of the ropes (representing motors) for there coordinates and reaction force (the same nodes are the bc pinned)

Then i saved the fieldoutput in a certain simple txt file which i was able to analyse via matlab.

Then i wrote a matlab script which created the points, attached them to the python script, copied it to a unique directory and even started the job.

This way, i was able to do geometric parametric studies in abaqus using matlab and python.

Code will be uploaded soon